# Regex/ JS : Добрый день, помогите пожалуйста удалить все буквы из строки после специальных символов(!, ? ,%, #, @ ...)

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки

let str = "Hello world !text"

Как задать список символов после которых я удаляю все лишнее ?

Заранее спасибо !

Comment: есть строка "Hello world ! text " нужно удалить текст специального символа, специальный символ может быть ( ! / ? / # / @/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

используйте позитивный просмотр назад `(?<=[символы])`, чтобы найти символы. и `.*` чтобы удалить все оставшееся.

```js
let txt = 'qwe !asd';
let re = /(?<=[!@&%]).*/;

console.log(txt.replace(re,''));
```